# Split single monitor into multiple using xrandr

Tags: linux, display, arch-linux, xrandr

I am trying to split my monitor into several screens of specific size and location. My tool of choice is `xrandr`. Does anyone know how to do this on Arch Linux?

Answer (score 2):

`xrandr` is your tool. Imagine your monitor’s name/output is `DVI-0` and it has a 1920x1080 panel. If your X11 is running it normally, then the following commands split it e.g. vertically in two screens, slightly asymmetric:

```
xrandr --setmonitor my-monitor-0 1000/1x1080/1+0+0 DVI-0
xrandr --setmonitor my-monitor-1 920/1x1080/1+1000+0 none
```

Now all window managers think you have two monitor and put one workspace/desktop on each. (Must be RandR-compliant, but all are.)

The four `/1` should be replaced by the real world millimeters each edge ends up occupying. (Used to calculate dots per inch, in case any app asks for it.)

More explanations can be found in my other answers:

- [Linux distro: How to use only part of monitor for display?](https://superuser.com/q/1780852)
- [How to disable bottom part of the screen with xrandr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/743997)
- [How to use xrandr to crop part of my monitor](https://superuser.com/q/1780351) (longest explanation with screenshots)

Answer (score 0):

To me that sounds pretty much like your looking for a tiling window manager.
I am running [i3-wm](http://i3wm.org/) for around four years and couldn't be any happier.
But there are a lot of other tiling wms.

- [Herbstluftwm](http://herbstluftwm.org/)
- [XMonad](http://xmonad.org/)
- [Awesome](https://awesomewm.org/)
- ..and many more

[here are some images](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=tiling+window+manager&iax=1&ia=images)

Comment: i3-wm won't do when you are operating with a display port hub or a docking station that has lesser support - two screens could merge and be shown as one very wide one.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `xrandr` for that: it is for controlling multiple outputs of graphic cards, that each have their own connector and go to different screens.

What you can do is to run another "nested" X server, like "xephyr" or the diverse VNC variants, for each "screen" you want to have: This will give you a window for each "screen", and if you make it borderless, it will probably have the effect you want. Not that each application will have to stick to the "screen" it's started on, unless you do an even more bizarre construction with `xpra` or `xdmx`.

Another option would be to convince the Window Manager to group application windows together in different zones on the screen, but I don't know of any WM which can do that.