# How to fix scaling on external monitor

Tags: windows-10, scaling

i cannot figure out how to fix scaling on my external monitor. I have connected to it via HDMI. I'm running windows 10. The content doesn't fit correctly on it.

Comment: More details are needed. What kind of monitor? Is your external monitor a 2nd monitor? Is that external monitor a TV, meaning does it have a remote that can change scaling? The more specific you are in what the problem is, and what your situation is, the more likely you will get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the fix i.e switched **Overscan** off from TV settings. 
I however have ever fixed this right from the windows display settings but i cannot figure how or cannot see the setting/option. I'm using windows 10 ver 1903, maybe it's a bug.

Comment: Windows or your computer has no control over your TV settings. So that fix is the only solution. Glad you figured it out.