# How to achieve 'split screen' capabilities (for gaming) on Linux

Tags: linux, display, multiple-monitors, xorg, xrandr

I'm trying to simulate the behavior of [universal split screen](https://universalsplitscreen.github.io/), which is for Windows only on Linux (Fedora, preferably Gnome/XOrg)
I found a lot about [`xrandr`](https://superuser.com/questions/1183820/split-single-monitor-into-multiple-using-xrandr), `Xephyr` and `xinerama`, but while all tutorials I found sound a lot like what I need, I didn't manage to "just" run two instances of an application (Terraria in my case) in one window, side by side.

The closest I found was

```
Xephyr -br -ac -noreset -screen 1920x600 :1 &
Xephyr -br -ac -noreset -screen 1920x600 :2 &
DISPLAY=:1 <command> &
DISPLAY=:2 <command> &
```

.. which is at least hard to use because you have two separate windows with their decorations.

Is there a way (without installing a tiling window manager, which would be my next approach) to "run  applications in one window which contains the output of different virtual displays in a static pre-defined manner"?

Or put less technical: is there a way to run applications which do not support 'side-by-side' operation in a side-by-side manner anyway on Linux?
Like with [Nucleus](https://nucleus-coop.github.io/), [universal split screen](https://universalsplitscreen.github.io/) or [tModLoader - Split Screen](https://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/split-screen-mod.70270/) (which somehow does not work for me)

Comment: Some Linux desktops, like Ratpoison, Herbsluftwm, i3, Awesome, and KDE Plasma desktop with specific settings enabled, can present application windows inside a desktop grid.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example repository for a script that was meant to behave like universal split screen or Nucleus. It uses tools like `firejail` (for handling inputs for each instance) and nested `weston` sessions (for window separation and it supports hardware acceleration unlike Xephyr) and `zenity` for ui+handling game windows. Currently it only supports game controllers and 2 players:

https://github.com/AhmedKJ/Co-op-on-Linux

```
# Example :
./Co-Op-On-linux.sh --quickrun 1280x720 /home/user/game/thegame
```

---

Even if it's not exactly what you're looking for, it should be a good starting point for building your own. The basic idea is you need at least:

- Something to handle window sizing/positioning/compositing, like Zephyr or Weston
- Something like [firejail](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Firejail) to grab P1/P2 inputs and redirect them to either window. X11 will generally direct all input to the focused window otherwise.
- And software/games that support running multiple instances, with regards to DRM/anti-cheat/file access

Comment: There is also https://github.com/klm682/minetest-splitscreen - I'll have a look into both and let you know if I got (one of) both to work (and how)..